# Google Maps API, without Login

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I have google maps api on my application and I would like to create new maps on google map from my application. I know that this can be done, but you have to login and than data is send to you account. What I would like to do is to send data to just one accout, so that my users will not need to sign in to google.

Comment: Are you using Google Static Maps API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are referring to API keys, starting with V3 you can access the Google Maps API without a key (it's no longer required).

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html#Welcome

> Note: This version of the Google Maps JavaScript API no longer needs API keys!